# Conversion of foreign/primary key from int to bigint in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL tables where there is a foreign key `ID` of type `int` and references a second table's `SID` primary key column - also an `int`.

I fill these tables from the C++ code where I have some wrappers to do for that reason.

Now, I want to change the datatype from `int` to `bigint` in the database, because I am going to store bigger integers here (bigger than maximum of `int`). Obviously, I'll read these integers from the database as well.

Is it safe to do so? Are there any hidden consequences?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. SQL is just a query language - not a database system - so we cannot really help you much....

Comment: No problems. Block (not lock!) tables completely, kill FK, alter tables, recreate FK, unblock tables.